# Is there a way to construct a circle through two points and a line using ruler and compass

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given two points and a line in the plane, is it possible to construct a circle tangent to the line which passes through the two points using ruler and compass?

For those who don't know, these are the rules of ruler and compass constructions:

you start with a set of initial objects (points, lines, etc.),

at every step you can do one of the following:

1. Construct a line or segment between two points in the set
2. Construct a circle with a segment within the set being its radius
3. Intersect two curves within the set

Each of these moves add the outcoming curve/point to the set.

Comment: Can you assume that the two points are on the same side of the line?

Comment: @paw88789 Good point. That had better be part of the given.

Comment: @TedShifrin this is incorrect. The point where the perpendicular bisector intersects the given line is not necessarily a point where the circle would be tangent to the line. In fact I have a counter example, the one where the line between the two given points is perpendicular to the given line. It also doesn't make algebraic sense since (assuming points are on the same side of the line) there should be 2 solutions, and intersecting lines gives only one, with no symmetries to the other cases.

Comment: Yes, of course you’re right.

Comment: This is a particular case of an [Apollonius problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius). [Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius#Inversive_methods) works very well.

Comment: @user58697, Never heard of Inversion before, Are such topics usually covered in Under-grad courses?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi I learned it in the 8th grade.

Comment: @user58697,I don't know it yet, Hence will learn it soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it goes,

It must be a necessary condition that two given points lie on Same side of given line

Now, Let the two given points be $P$ and $Q$, let the given line be $L$

**Case-1**-When segment $PQ$ is not parallel to line $L$

Join points $P$ and $Q$ and extend it to cut the line $L$ at point $S$
Measure distance $PS$ using compass,Here in my case,$P$ is nearer to point $S$ than $Q$,

Now mark a point on extended line on Other side Of segment $PS$ with a distance equal to that of $PS$,let this new point be $R$,

Draw perpendicular Bisector of Segment $RQ$,Mark point $G$ where it intersects the segment $RQ$

Taking $G$ as centre and $GR$ as radius,Draw a circle $A$

Draw a perpendicular $X$ Passing through point $S$,Mark point $F$ where it intersects the circle $A$

Measure Length $SF$ using compass or ruler,Mark Point $Z$ on given line $L$ along initial side of $S$ with length $SF$ measured

The Point $Z$ is the point of tangency
Of required Circle, Now Draw Any perpendicular Bisectors of segments out of Segment $PQ$,Segment $QZ$ and Segment $PZ$

Mark the intersection of these any two perpendicular Bisectors as point $K$,it is the Centre of Required Circle

Finally draw a circle Using Found centre and three Points, I will be uploading a Geogebra Image soon ,I don't have enough Time to type..

[image]

Line in orange color is original line given,$PQZ$ is the required Circle,$Q$ and $P$ are given points

**Case-2**- When $PQ$ is parallel to line $L$, Draw Perpendicular bisector line $J$ of segment $PQ$ ,Mark it's intersection point with Line $L$ as $O$, this point $O$ is point of tangency, Repeat last steps of case -1 to find required Circle

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

I have added an image for More Understanding, Now let's understand what we have done geometrically in first case

The basic property used is the secant tangent theoram of circle,[see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent%E2%80%93secant_theorem)

Now as the basic idea is clear,we needed to find the geometric mean of $SP$ and $SQ$ equivalent to geometric mean of $SR$ and $SQ$ which is precisely the length of $SZ$

Now, To find geometric mean, We have a nice property in right angle triangle,see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem)

In order to use this,We needed to create a right angled triangle,and we know that in a circle, Any traingle with one point on Circle and base as Diameter make One nice right triangle,So we made circle with diameter $RQ$ ,which we created using point $G$ or midpoint as centre,

Later we dropped a perpendicular from $S$ to new circle to use Geometric mean theoram ,as mentioned ,We found the geometric mean to be precisely the length of $SF$ ,hence we marked point $Z$ on line $L$ such that $SF=SZ$

Hence finding the point of tangency,Other than this, It is now simple to draw a circle knowing $3$ Points on it

Comment: That's an amazing solution and explanation and it all makes pure sense. I would have marked that as correct answer earlier but i accidentally put R on the wrong side, so good thing that this diagram was here to help after the edit. I thought about using the secant tangent theorem and tangent angle theorem but I didn't think about your genius way of reconstructing the geometric mean of the segments in such a convenient way. Thank you this solution kind of made my day.

Comment: @עמיתחילרמן,Glad It helped you..

Answer (score 0):

For an algebraic approach:

By an astute choice of coordinate system, let the line be the $x$ axis of the coordinate plane, $P$ be at point $(0,1)$ and $Q$ be at point $(s,t)$. Note that this can describe every possible situation by choice of coordinate system. We need to find a point $R=(x,y)$ such that

$$d(R,x_{axis})=d(R,P)=d(R,Q)$$

and show that these $x$ and $y$ are constructible. Of course, it is easy to see that the distance between $R$ and the $x$ axis is $y$. Thus, we have to solve the equations

$$x^2+(y-1)^2=y^2$$

$$(x-s)^2+(y-t)^2=y^2$$

The solutions to these equations are rather long and case dependent (found [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%28x%5E2%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%3D%3Dy%5E2%26%26%28x-s%29%5E2%2B%28y-t%29%5E2%3D%3Dy%5E2%2C%28x%2Cy%29%29)) but the important thing is that both $x$ and $y$ can be created out of multiplication, addition, and squareroots of $s$, $t$, and integers. Thus, we are assured that they are constructible.

Comment: Well it makes sense and now I'm sure that it's constructible. But I think actually constructing it like this is kinda annoying, isn't it?

Comment: True, the algebraic approach is most useful to **prove** something is constructable. In theory, you could follow the 'proceduce' (ie formula) for $x$ and $y$ to find point $R$ but that is definately a pain. Only time I've seen it done is when people construct a $17$-gon